# database design bigger table vs split table have the same col

Tags: nhibernate, database-design, orm, relational-database

i have a database program for store as you know there is too type of invoice in it one for the thing i bought and the other for me when i sold them the two table is almost identical like

invoice table
Id
customerName
date
invoiceType

and invoiceDetails which have
id 
invoiceId
item
price
amount

my question is simple its what best to keep the design like that or split every table for two sperate tabels
couple of my friend suggest splitting the tables as one for saleInvoice and the other for buyInvoice to speed the time for querying
so whats the pro and con of every abrouch i feel that if i split them its like i dont follow DRY rule
i am using Nhibernate BTW so its kindda weird to have to identical class with different names

Answer (score 1):

Both approached would work.  If you use the single table approach, then the invoiceType column would be your discriminator field.  In your nHibernate mapping, this discriminator field would be used by nHibernate to decide which type (i.e. a purchase or a sale) to instantiate for a given row in the table (see section 5.1.6 of the [nHibernate mapping guide](http://knol.google.com/k/nhibernate-chapter-5-basic-o-r-mapping#).  For ad hoc SQL queries or reporting queries, you could create two views, one to return only rows with invoiceType = purchase and one to return only rows where invoiceType=sales.

Alternatively, you could create two separate tables, one for purchase and one for sales.  As you point out, these two tables would have nearly identical schemas and nhibernate mapping files.

If you are anticipating very high transaction volumes, you would want to put purchases and sales on two different physical discs.  With two different tables, this can be accomplished by putting them into different file groups.  With a single table, you still could accomplish this by creating a [SQL Server Partitioned Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188730.aspx).  Before you go to this trouble, you might want to evaluate if this really is necessary and that disc access to the table is really going to be the performance bottleneck.  You don't want to spend a lot of time doing premature optimization if it is not necessary.

My preference would be to have a single table with a discriminator column, to better follow DRY principles.  Unless I had solid numbers that indicated that indicated it was necessary, I would hold off implementing a partitioned table until if and when it became necessary.

Comment: thanks really appreciate it what i did is make the current entity as base class and drive to classes from it so the only think that get repeated the mapping not the functionality so i have to separte table but i deal with them as almost one class

Answer (score 1):

I'd ask myself, how do I intend to use this information? Will I need sales and buy invoices in the same queries? Am I likely to need specialized information eventually (highly likely in my experience) for each type? And if I do will I need to have child tables for only 1 type? How would that affect referntial integrity? Would a change to one automatically mean I needed a change to the other? How large is the table likely to be (It would have to be in the multi-millions before I would consider that it might need to be split out only due to size). How likely is it that I would get the information mixed up by accident if they are in the same table and include both when I didn't want to? The answers would determine whether I needed to split it out for me. I would tend to see these as two separate functions and it would take alot to convince me to put them in one table.